# npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE when install Shopify starter-theme-master

Tags: node.js, json, laravel, npm, shopify

I'm new to learn Coding and Absolute Beginner.

I'm trying to learn Shopify Theme Dev, so I have this sample code for installing NPM Run Dev. and I am trying to get it work but after running npm install followed by npm start I receive on terminal the following error:

```
sh: cross-env: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! meganicondev@1.0.0 development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the meganicondev@1.0.0 development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/meganicon/.npm/_logs/2020-07-29T03_34_07_011Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! meganicondev@1.0.0 dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the meganicondev@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/meganicon/.npm/_logs/2020-07-29T03_34_07_028Z-debug.log
Meganicon@Miska-Mekbuk-Amatir meganicondev % 
Meganicon@Miska-Mekbuk-Amatir meganicondev % npm cache clean --force
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
Meganicon@Miska-Mekbuk-Amatir meganicondev % npm run dev            

> meganicondev@1.0.0 dev /Users/meganicon/meganicondev
> npm run development


> meganicondev@1.0.0 development /Users/meganicon/meganicondev
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

sh: cross-env: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! meganicondev@1.0.0 development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the meganicondev@1.0.0 development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/meganicon/.npm/_logs/2020-07-29T03_41_32_515Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! meganicondev@1.0.0 dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the meganicondev@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/meganicon/.npm/_logs/2020-07-29T03_41_32_532Z-debug.log
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "meganicondev",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "laravel-mix": "^5.0.4"
  }
}
```

And finally my log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/opt/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'dev' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.7
3 info using node@v12.18.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle meganicondev@1.0.0~predev: meganicondev@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle meganicondev@1.0.0~dev: meganicondev@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle meganicondev@1.0.0~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle meganicondev@1.0.0~dev: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/.bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/meganicon/Developer/flutter/bin:/Users/meganicon/Developer/flutter/bin
9 verbose lifecycle meganicondev@1.0.0~dev: CWD: /Users/meganicon/meganicondev
10 silly lifecycle meganicondev@1.0.0~dev: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run development' ]
11 silly lifecycle meganicondev@1.0.0~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle meganicondev@1.0.0~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: meganicondev@1.0.0 dev: `npm run development`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid meganicondev@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/meganicon/meganicondev
16 verbose Darwin 19.5.0
17 verbose argv "/opt/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v12.18.3
19 verbose npm  v6.14.7
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error meganicondev@1.0.0 dev: `npm run development`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the meganicondev@1.0.0 dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: try with `npm run dev`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like `cross-env` is not installed. Try installing it globally and see if the error persists.

```
npm install -g cross-env
```

Edit: cross-env actually needs to be installed globally in order to be run from the terminal (I'm using cmd).